# Python submit post data using mechanize

Tags: python, post, mechanize, urlencode, html-post

The url that i have to submit to the server looks like this:

```
www.mysite.com/manager.php?checkbox%5B%5D=5&checkbox%5B%5D=4&checkbox%5B%5D=57&self=19&submit=Go%21
```

The post data I put it like this:

```
data = {'checkbox%5B%5D': '4', ....and so on... 'self': '19', 'submit': 'Go%21'}
```

I encode it:

```
data = urllib.urlencode(orbs)
```

and this is how i run it:

```
resp = mechanize.Request('http://mysite.com/manager.php', data)
cj.add_cookie_header(resp)
res = mechanize.urlopen(resp)
print res.read()
```

And the error says: That i didnt select any item.
How can I do it right without using br.select_form(nr=0) because I have nested forms?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You double-encoded the checkbox field names; you should use `checkbox[]` instead of `checkbox%5B%5D`. Also, because that key name is reused, you probably can't use a dictionary to gather up the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Url encoding is the process of changing string (i.e '[]') into percent-encoded string (i.e '%5B%5D') and url decoding is the opposite operation. So:

```
checkbox%5B%5D=5&checkbox%5B%5D=4&checkbox%5B%5D=57&self=19&submit=Go%21
```

is after decoding:

```
checkbox[]=5&checkbox[]=4&checkbox[]=57&self=19&submit=Go!
```

In your code you're actually encofing an already-encoded url:

```
data = {'checkbox%5B%5D': '4', ....and so on... 'self': '19', 'submit': 'Go%21'}
data = urllib.urlencode(orbs)
```

Instead use decoded data and pass it to urlencode:

```
data = {'checkbox[]': '4', ....and so on... 'self': '19', 'submit': 'Go!'}
data = urllib.urlencode(orbs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer but DJC was faster than you.