# How to input values to javascript function from mechanize python

Tags: javascript, python, mechanize

Im currently trying to input values to a page through mechanize , but there are two date fields like

```
    <td align="center"><script>DateInput('startDate', true, 'YYYY-MM-DD')</script> </td>
```

from the source "calendarDateInput.js"

How can i input my own values to this through mechanize?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is this data posted in HTTP request or it's handled only by JavaScript?

Comment: it is handled only by Javascript

Comment: Then mechanize can't do this. Use selenium

Comment: okay thankyou. i will start using selenium

Comment: @ton1c : If the data is posted in HTTP request , how can i input my own values ?

Comment: There are a lot of tutorial on this, take a look at similar question [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903034/python-submit-post-data-using-mechanize) or [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720470/using-python-and-mechanize-to-submit-form-data-and-authenticate)